# How to replace output value of an if statement with either the min or max given value given certain conditions

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to calculate fee value of different products, but there is a min and max fee value. If the fee charged is $15, but the min value = $1 and the max value =$ 10 , since the charged fee is greater than the max fee i want the $15 to be replaced by $10 and vice versa for fees less than $1.

I tried using the IF condition in python but it only outputs the calculated fee charged.
This is how the code looks like

```
Id   Product   pricing option   size    percentage_charge   fee  calctd_fee
 1   cookies    BUNDL           small       0.044            50    2.2
 2   chips      REBATE          LARGE       0.044            12    0.53
 3   spray      PAYAS           MEDIUM      0.044            550   24.2
```

The maxfee = $10 and minfee =$1

The expected output is to change the spray and chips value to the min and max fee:

```
    Id   Product   pricing option   size    perntge_charge   fee  calctd_fee
 1   cookies    BUNDL           small       0.044            50     2.2
 2   chips      REBATE          LARGE       0.044            12     **1**
 3   spray      PAYAS           MEDIUM      0.044            550    **10**
```

i used the code below:

```
def fee(df):

    if (df['product'] == 'COOKIES') and (df['SIZE'] == 'BIG') and (df['Pricing_Option']=='BUNDL'):
        return df['fee'] * df['percentage_charge']

    if df['fee'] * df['percentage_charge'] > maxvalue:
        return maxvalue

    if df['fee'] * df['percentage_charge'] < minvalue:
        return minvalue

   else:
        return df['Value_of_product'] * df['percentage_charge']


df['CALCULATED_CHARGE'] = df.apply(fee, axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

For what you're trying to do I think the axis should be set to 0. Try this

```
def fee(row):

    if (row['product'] == 'COOKIES') and (row['SIZE'] == 'BIG') and (row['Pricing_Option']=='BUNDL'):
        return row['fee'] * row['percentage_charge']

    if row['fee'] * row['percentage_charge'] > maxvalue:
        return maxvalue

    if row['fee'] * row['percentage_charge'] < minvalue:
        return minvalue

   else:
        return df['Value_of_product'] * df['percentage_charge']


df['CALCULATED_CHARGE'] = df.apply(fee, axis = 0)
```

I'm not entirely sure if this what you want since I don't know the purpose of the first if statement and you also haven't defined the `maxvalue` and `minvalue` variables inside the `fee` function